# ASP.NET Forms Authentication Ticket Timeout

Tags: c#, asp.net, forms, cookies, forms-authentication

Whats the best way to create a custom ASP.NET forms authentication ticket with a specified timeout? The timeout value is coming from a database not the web.config.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

[Explained: Forms Authentication in ASP.NET 2.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa480476.aspx)

```
 FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(1,
        "userName",
        DateTime.Now,
        DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(30), // value of time out property
        false, // Value of IsPersistent property
        String.Empty,
        FormsAuthentication.FormsCookiePath);
```